# Reference promotion for a derived class with no data members

Tags: c++, reference, derived-class

I have an interesting problem involving a hierarchy of classes in a library that I maintain. A very simplified view of the situation is as follows:

```cpp
class Base {
// private data + public interface to said data 
};

class ClassA : public Base {
// Behaviour
};

class ClassB : public Base {
// Behaviour
};
```

So here I have a class that contains the data privately and has a consistent interface. In reality this is a templated class with lots of different storage models. The two derived classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` purely add different implementations of the same behaviour and do not contain any data. It *should* be within the realms of possibility to convert a reference to an instance of `ClassA` to one of `ClassB` without invoking any copies. Of course, one can use

```cpp
ClassA a;
B& a_bref = *reintepret_cast<B*>(&a);
```

But this breaks all the rules. My question: Is there a safe way to implement such a conversion operator?

Comment: declare and implement a [cast operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Comment: Wait a second... Without copies? No. A `ClassA` is not a `ClassB`. They have some commonality in `Base`, but that's it. Both can be used as a `Base`, but `ClassA` and `ClassB` could have wildly different signatures in memory, so looking for `ClassB`-specific stuff in a `ClassA` is doomed from the get go. Some of the restrictions have been weakening over time, and you can take advantage of similarities between [Standard Layout classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType), and these classes are simple enough to qualify, but that's mostly because they contain nothing.

Comment: Sadly I think the correct way to think about this structure is not in terms of a class hierarchy but instead as a system of traits implemented for a data storage class (c.f. the Rust model)

Comment: You're in one of those "Probably would work" cases because you aren't changing the data around in the subclasses, but all it takes is one programmer coming along later to totally screw things up. You might want to look at the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It soulds like a decent direction to go for what I understand of your use-case.

Comment: actually, if class has virtual functions, reinterpret_cast will not help you, the object will still have reference to vtable of actual class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Multiple inheritance

One way to achieve your goal is through multiple inheritance.

```
class A : virtual public Base {
//...
};

class B : virtual public Base {
//...
};

class AorB : public A, public B {
//...
};
```

With virtual inheritance, you only have one `Base` instance that is shared between the `A` and `B` that make up `AorB`. This approach means you need to create a class that knows which subtypes you might want to flip through. This may or may not be a problem for you, depending on your use case.

#### Strategy

A more flexible approach may be to treat `A` and `B` as strategies, and treat `Base` as the context. In this method, you would not use inheritance. You can separate the data from the interface, so that `A` and `B` can inherit the accessor methods, but reference the data.

```
class Base {
    friend class Base_Interface;
    //...
};

class Base_Interface {
    Base &context_;
    //...
    Base_Interface (Base &context) : context_(context) {}
    template <typename X> operator X () { return context_; }
};

class A : public Base_Interface {
    //...
    A (Base &context) : Base_Interface(context) {}
};

class B : public Base_Interface {
    //...
    B (Base &context) : Base_Interface(context) {}
};
```

Perhaps lazily, there is a template conversion method to allow users of the `Base_Interface` to convert to some other class that accepts the `Base` in its constructor. It works out if  `Base` has no public members, with `Base_Interface` as its only friend.